# Getting storage Account type for ARM Setup

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Please help me to get the Account type (i.e LRS or GRS or ZRS )of the storage accounts for ARM setup.
i have ran `Get-Azurermstorageaccount` , but it is not exposing any methods to get that. However i am able to get account type in ASM Setup using the command `Get-Azurestorageaccount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use this command:

```
PS C:\> (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName back -Name "jasondisk321").Sku

       Name     Tier
       ----     ----
StandardLRS Standard
```

Comment: command `(Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName back -Name "jasondisk321").sku.Name` will get `standardLRS`